# How can I get 6 explosive power?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

There's some rubble I can't get past in the cave where my Nemesis is. Apparently I need to have 6 explosive power to get past it, but I have no idea what that means or how I acquire it.

How do I get 6 explosive power so I can get past the impassable rubble?

Comment: 6 Fizzing spore pods from angry mushroom guy in the fungal nethers

Comment: @Aequitas you should expand that to a full answer

Comment: @GodEmperorDune I don't have a clue what any of those words mean tho, I just searched the KoL wiki and found that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need fight [Angry Mushroom Guys](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Angry_mushroom_guy) in [The Fungal Nethers area](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/The_Fungal_Nethers). They are the only enemies with a chance to drop [fizzling spore pods](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Fizzing_spore_pod) which are the explosive power mentioned. Improving your item drop rate through equipment and buffs is also helpful, as these are not guaranteed drops.

After you collect 6 fizzling spore pods, visit [the impassable rubble](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Rubble,_Rubble,_Toil_and_Trouble) and choose the option to blast it open.